# CSS Transitions on dynamically added content using vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm using a router, specifically [Navigo](https://github.com/krasimir/navigo).

I intend to fade out existing content, then add the new content fading in.

I change content of my 'main' div, on routes configured on the router.

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
```

My current approach, involves checking if there is content inside div, then adding a hide class to it and adding an event listener, to animation end that changes the content. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. Once the hide class is added, the first div that was added remains there without being removed, most likely because the `animationend` event is not being fired ever again.

Edit: I have since updated my approach, to fade out the parent content, then add the content on animation end. Also for compatibility, I have included all transitions.

Here is my current setup, most of it anyways

Then via js,

```
const routes: {path: string, content: string}[] = [{
        path: 'about',
        content: `<div class="about-content main-content">...</div>`
    },
    ...
]

const transitionEvent = (() => {
    var el: HTMLElement = document.createElement("faux");
  
    var transitions:Record<string, string> = {
      "transition"      : "transitionend",
      "OTransition"     : "oTransitionEnd",
      "MozTransition"   : "transitionend",
      "WebkitTransition": "webkitTransitionEnd"
    }
  
    for (let t in transitions){
      if (el.style[t] !== undefined){
        return transitions[t];
      }
    }
})();

const router = new Navigo('/');

const contentDom = document.getElementById('main');

routes.forEach(route => {
    router.on(route.path, () => {
        let temp = (e: Event) => {
            console.log(e);
            contentDom.removeEventListener(transitionEvent, temp, false);
            contentDom.innerHTML = route.content;
            contentDom.className = 'transition-in';
        };
        contentDom.addEventListener(transitionEvent, temp, false);
        contentDom.className = 'transition-out';
    })
})
```

and finally css,

```css
.main-content{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1
        &.transition-in {
            animation: slide-up 1s ease-in-out;
        }

        &.transition-out {       
            animation: slide-up 1s ease-in-out;
            animation-direction: reverse;
        }
}
@keyframes slide-up {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(20px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can use pseudoclass :not() with :empty to check with only CSS is div is empty/not empty

Comment: Yes but that would not fade out the div before removing it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this. My mistake was I was trying the transitionend event on an animation.

changing my css to

```css
.main-content{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

and then my js to set opacity instead,

```
routes.forEach(route => {
    router.on(route.path, () => {
        let temp = (e: Event) => {
            console.log(e);
            contentDom.removeEventListener(transitionEvent, temp, false);
            contentDom.innerHTML = route.content;
            contentDom.style.opacity = '1';
        };
        contentDom.addEventListener(transitionEvent, temp, false);
        contentDom.style.opacity = '0';
    })
})
```

fixed my issue.